# One-factor mean-reverting model parameter estimation with Kalman Filter - LinAlgError: 13-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite

Tags: python, optimization, kalman-filter

[image]

My code so far is as follows, starting from the simplest case of estimating only k:

```
import scipy
from pykalman.sqrt import CholeskyKalmanFilter
import numpy as np

k = 0.0001
T = np.array([1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16,20,24,28,32,34,35] , dtype=int) #maturities
delta = 1e-9
x = k

#Optimisation

def obj(x):
    k = x[0]
    Q = (1 - k) *np.eye(1)
    Z = np.exp(-k*T)
    Z =Z[:, None] #reshape to 2 dim
    transition_covariance=delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(1)
    print(transition_covariance.shape)
    observation_covariance=0.001*np.eye(len(T))
    print(observation_covariance.shape)
    print(Q.shape)
    print(Z.shape)
    
    kf = CholeskyKalmanFilter(transition_matrices=np.eye(1)*(1-k),
                  observation_matrices= Z,
                  transition_covariance=transition_covariance,
                  observation_covariance=observation_covariance,
                  )
    
    lk =  kf.loglikelihood(X) # X is my observed data, 1016 rows × 17 columns
    return -lk

x = np.array([k])

k = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, x)
```

However, when I run the optimization I get the error

LinAlgError: 13-th leading minor of the array is not positive definite

I have tried to use both standard Kalman Filter and the "square root" filter (CholeskyKalmanFilter), however with the same results. Any idea how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution! Using a different scipy algorithm there is a solution to the optimisation. The optimised factors provide a good fit for the model.

Here is the code:

```
k =  0.00000000000001 
sigma = 0.00000000000001
T = np.array([1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16,20,24,28,32,34,35] , dtype=int) #maturities
x = k, sigma

#objective function

def obj(x):
    k = x[0]
    sigma = x[1]
    Q = (1 - k) *np.eye(1)
    Z = np.exp(-k*T)
    Z =Z[:, None] #reshape to 2 dim
    transition_covariance= (sigma**2)* np.eye(1)

    observation_covariance=0.001*np.eye(len(T))

    
    kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices=Q,
                  observation_matrices= Z,
                  transition_covariance=transition_covariance,
                  observation_covariance=observation_covariance)

    lk =  kf.loglikelihood(X) # X is my observed data, 1016 rows × 17 columns
    return -lk #negative to maximise minimise algorithm

x = np.array([k, sigma])

opt_params = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, x, method= 'TNC')
```